# rails helper - conditionally yield block or fallback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I create a helper to yield content in a block OR fallback to something else?

Something like:

```
def yield_or_fallback
  if item.foo?
    yield
  else
    "bar"
end
```

```
<%= item.yield_or_fallback do %>
  "hello"
<% end %>
```

###### when `item.foo == true`

```
"hello
```

###### when `item.foo == false`

```
"bar"
```

The above does not work. How can I accomplish something like this with a helper?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `item` to that method

```
def yield_or_fallback(item)
  if item.foo?
    yield
  else
    "bar"
  end
end
```

and call it like this

```
<%= yield_or_fallback(item) do %>
  "hello"
<% end %>
```

But given that your condition is pretty simple I would prefer to have the view code more explicit:

```
<%= if item.foo %>
  hello
<% else %>
  bar
<% end %>
```